# Any subcollection $\mathcal A_1$ of a locally finite collection $\mathcal A$ of subsets of $X$ is locally finite.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing, quantifiers

Any subcollection $\mathcal A_1$ of a locally finite collection $\mathcal A$ of subsets of $X$ is locally finite.

### Proof

Let $\mathcal A_1$ be any subcollection of $\mathcal A$ i.e., $\mathcal A_1\subset \mathcal A.$

Let $x\in X$ and $\mathcal A$ is locally finite,  so there exists a nbhd $U$ of $x$ that intersects only finitely many elements $A_1, A_2, A_3,..., A_n$ of $\mathcal A$.

More precisely,$A_i\cap U\neq \phi$,where $1\le i \le n $.

Since,$\mathcal A_1\subset \mathcal A.$,so if any element of {$A_i:1\le i \le n$} is in $\mathcal A_1,$ so $U$ intersects only finitely many elements of $\mathcal A_1$,making it locally finite collection of subsets of $X$.

**Please check the proof critically up to here, especially the use of quantifiers.**. If there is some scope of improvement in the proof or some elegant method other than this please let me know...

My question is "What if no element of {$A_i:1\le i \le n$} is in $\mathcal A_1$?"

Comment: Locally Finite: A collection of subsets of a topological space X is said to be locally finite if each point in the space has a neighborhood that intersects only finitely many of the sets in the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is okay.

You could also formulate it like this:

Collection $\mathcal A$ is locally finite if and only if for every $x\in X$  a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ exists that satisfies:$$\{A\in\mathcal A\mid A\cap U\neq\varnothing\}\text{ is a finite set}\tag1$$
From $\mathcal A_1\subseteq\mathcal A$ it follows directly that: $$\{A\in\mathcal A_1\mid A\cap U\neq\varnothing\}\subseteq\{A\in\mathcal A\mid A\cap U\neq\varnothing\}\tag2$$so if $\mathcal A$ is indeed locally finite then from $(1)$ and $(2)$ it follows directly that also:$$\{A\in\mathcal A_1\mid A\cap U\neq\varnothing\}\text{ is a finite set}\tag3$$
We conclude that $\mathcal A_1$ is also locally finite.

Concerning your question:

If $\{A\in\mathcal A_1\mid A\cap U\neq\varnothing\}$ is empty (in your words no element of $\{A_i\mid 1\leq i\leq n\}$ is in $\mathcal A_1$) then the set mentioned under $(3)$ is empty *hence is finite*.

So nothing is wrong then with the reasoning.

The less elements a collection $\mathcal A$ contains the more likely it is that the collection is locally finite.

In specific the empty collection is locally finite.

Comment: :your last statement made my day...thank you...Merry Christmas!!

Comment: Merry Christmas to you as well, of course.